# Django admin page refused to connect

Tags: python, django

So I'm realtively new on Python and Django . I was creating a blog application using django and I'm facing problems regarding my django admin page. I did all the migrations and created superuser as told in a paritcular tutorial. But after that when I'm trying to open Django admin page , it says that my localhost refused to connect

```
 C:\Users\HP\Desktop\django_project>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 27, 2020 - 09:27:16
Django version 3.0.8, using settings 'django_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[27/Jul/2020 09:27:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3899
[27/Jul/2020 09:27:33] "GET /static/blog/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[27/Jul/2020 09:27:34] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2317
```

My urls.py looks like this...

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

And my Installed apps and Middleware in `settings.py` looks like..

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

I'm using Python 3.7 , Django version 3.0.8 and Windows 10.

Comment: Does other routes work?
Also check if you have debug=True or not

Comment: @GauravJain Yes the Debug is set as True.

Comment: Does your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting include either ` ["127.0.0.1", "localhost"]`

Comment: @Ben My ALLOWED_HOSTS is an empty list

Comment: Add `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1", "localhost"]` to your settings file.

Comment: I did that and it is still showing the same thing and this message "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3899

Comment: Hi @perpetualstudent, how did you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying the server to run at port 8000.

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Did you try to connect to localhost:8000 or localhost only?

Comment: Another possibility is something else is taking your localhost, instead of Django. I would install a Nginx server in this case to take connection then pass to the Django server

Answer (score 0):

Just replace "watch?v=" with "/embed/".
For example:
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NelgXtXYIko`
becomes
`https://www.youtube.com/embed/NelgXtXYIko`